# why do i get 'Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget' when nothing is wrong with my expanded widgets?

Tags: flutter

i am trying to make a bmi calculator app, i have 2 reusable cards that i am trying to change the color of when clicked, if the "male" one got clicked it would light up and turn off the other one and vice verca.

however, when i click on it it works once, but when i click again it throws me these errors:

I/flutter ( 4381): Another exception was thrown: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
I/flutter ( 4381): Another exception was thrown: Each child must be laid out exactly once.

i tried to rethink my if statement but it seemed right, i also googled these errors, i got results relating to expanded widgets, but my expanded widgets seem to be laid out just fine.

now i am suspecting it has to do with my reusable card widget, but i am not sure.

here are snippets of my code:

input page:

```
const activeCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  
  Gender? selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                          ? activeCardColor
                          : inactiveCardColor,
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars, label: 'MALE'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.female;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                          ? activeCardColor
                          : inactiveCardColor,
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                        label: 'FEMALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                colour: activeCardColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    colour: activeCardColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                  colour: activeCardColor,
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

reusable card widget:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard({
    super.key,
    required this.colour,
    this.cardChild,
  });

  final Color colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: cardChild,
    );
  }
}
```

i appreciate any help!

Comment: You have children Expanded with a parent as Expanded. This is the wrong way you've implemented your widgets. Take a look here as this can help you: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: The other thing is that you cannot put together a bunch of Expanded all together. Expanded make sense to use there when you have a fixed space by one side then you want to occupied all the available space remained (as a basic rule)

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj
 thank you so much, i just got it fixed, i was confused because my if statement was not working, so i thought it was the problem, but as soon as i fixed the expanded widget everything got into place, i appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: you're welcome bro!!